# Duplicate element elimination from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray`. I have synthesized it as well. I am adding objects to it from a method by xml extraction of some file names etc. Now in my array there is the occurrence of same elements multiple times. I need to eliminate the multiple objects and get only unique ones. How can this be done? I tried the code below but then there arise some errors.

```
NSString *AName = [CompleteFileName_string1 substringWithRange:ArtistRange];  
[array_artist addObject:AName];
for(int i=0; i < [array_artist count]; i++)
{
    if([[array_artist objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[array_artist objectAtIndex:i+1]])
    {
        [[array_artist objectAtIndex:i+1]=NULL];
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

EDIT*** i need to eliminate by ignoring case sensitivity too...

Comment: When you are adding objects from XML you have to just check if(![array_artis containsObject:stringFromXML])                              {[array_artist addObject:stringFromXML];

Comment: yeah its fine now... can u please make it as answer? so that  can select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a tempArray as golbally

When you are adding objects from XML you have to just check

```
NSString *upCaseString=[stringFromXML uppercaseString];

if(![tempArray containsObject:upCaseString]) {    
    [array_artist addObject:stringFromXML]; 

    [tempArray addObject:upCaseString];
}
```

Comment: then case sensitivity? its not comparing that

Answer (score 1):

Go With [NSSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just simply check if the array contains the object:

```
if(![yourArray containsObject:stringFromXML]) 
{
             [yourArray addObject:stringFromXML]
}
```

Comment: i got this answer as a first comment. But there comes a problem like the element is getting added without checking case sensitivity.. how can this be removed?

Comment: Other ways round is you can use can insensitive comparison of strings in your original code.if([[array_artist objectAtIndex:i] &&[array_artist objectAtIndex:i+1] caseInsensitiveCompare:@"True"] == NSOrderedSame])
    {
         Add element
    }

Comment: how to do that? i have an NSString AName and this is to be added to the array. how to check the case insensitivity?

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Code..
First Add All values in array_artist

```
int i1=0;

tempArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

while (i1 < [array_artist count]) {     

    if ([tempArray containsObject:[array_artist objectAtIndex:i1]) {
    //Do not Add    
    }
    else {
       //Add  object
       [tempArray addObject:array_artist:i1];           
    }

    i1++;
}
```

Comment: yes. Your code is not working for me. But the code by Rao Rules is fine still elements are not eliminated if there is change in case. eg: cat cAt are added even though they are same.

Comment: @Priya ..Have you used caseInsensitive comparison code i wrote in last comment.?

Answer (score 0):

```
if([[array_artist objectAtIndex:i] &&[array_artist objectAtIndex:i+1] caseInsensitiveCompare:@"True"] == NSOrderedSame])
```

{
 Add element
 }

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
NSArray *out = [NSSet setWithArray:in].allObjects;
```

?